# Правильный путь до папок в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

В yii2 решил создать папку public_html и перенести туда файлы web из fronted и также создать в public_html папку admin с файлами из web backend 
т.е. файл autoload находится в D:\sites\site\yii2\vendor
bootstrap - D:\sites\site\yii2\common\config

Файлы из web fronted теперь D:\sites\site\public_html
Файлы из web backend D:\sites\site\public_html\admin

Как верно указать точный путь в index.php в этом случае?

```html
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/public_html/yii2/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/public_html/yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/public_html/yii2/common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/public_html/yii2/fronted/config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/public_html/yii2/common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/public_html/yii2/common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/public_html/yii2/fronted/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/public_html/yii2/fronted/config/main-local.php')
);

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

[image: webfronted]

Answer (score 0):

У вас frontend точно правильно написано?

```
   <?php
    defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
    defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

    require(__DIR__ . '/../yii2/vendor/autoload.php');
    require(__DIR__ . '/../yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
    require(__DIR__ . '/../yii2/common/config/bootstrap.php');
    require(__DIR__ . '/../yii2/frontend/config/bootstrap.php');

    $config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
        require(__DIR__ . '/../yii2/common/config/main.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/../yii2/common/config/main-local.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/../yii2/frontend/config/main.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/../yii2/frontend/config/main-local.php')
    );

    (new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```